# Find the nature of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left( \frac{u_n}{1 + u_n} \right)^\alpha$, where $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty u_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Knowing that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty u_n$ is a convergent series, with $u_n \ge 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, find the nature of the following series ($\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left( \frac{u_n}{1 + u_n} \right)^\alpha$$

Since $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty u_n$ is convergent, we are sure that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n = 0$. But I don't have any idea on how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that eventually

$$\left( \frac{u_n}{1 + u_n} \right)^\alpha \le \left( u_n\right)^\alpha \le u_n$$

which converges for $\alpha\ge 1$ by direct comparison test and for $0<\alpha <1$ given that $\sum u_n^\alpha$ converges then also the given series converges otherwise given that $\sum u_n^\alpha$ diverges then since

$$\left( \frac{u_n}{1 + u_n} \right)^\alpha=\frac{u_n^\alpha}{(1 + u_n)^\alpha} \ge \frac{u_n^\alpha}{1 + \alpha u_n}=u_n^\alpha+O(u_n^{1+\alpha})$$

also the given series diverges.

Comment: I understood the second part, but I don't quite understand how to use the Limit Comparison Test for $\alpha \ge 1$. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n^\alpha \mathbin{/} u_n^{(1 + \alpha) \mathbin{/} 2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n^{(\alpha - 1) \mathbin{/} 2}$. What should I do from here..?

Comment: We have that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (u_n)^{(\alpha - 1) \mathbin{/} 2}=0$ and since  $\sum (u_n)^{(1 + \alpha) \mathbin{/} 2}$ converges also the given $\sum (u_n)^\alpha$ converge by LCT.

Comment: Oh of course, the limit is $0$. But why does $\sum u_n^{(1 + \alpha) \mathbin{/} 2}$ converge? Should I repeat the test recursively, until $\alpha$ becomes less than $1$?

Comment: @IulianOleniuc Simply because evetually $u_n^{(1 + \alpha) \mathbin{/} 2} \le u_n$.

Comment: Right, so the test should be repeated. Thanks!

Comment: @IulianOleniuc Oh yes sorry, we can avoid LCT and conclude by direct comparison test! I've realized that now. It is simpler than that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try two cases: $\alpha \ge 1$, $0<\alpha<1$, and $\alpha \le 0$. For $\alpha\ge 1$, you can probably use Limit Comparison; for $\alpha<1$, look at different $p$-series; for $\alpha\le 0$, try the Term Test.

Comment: For the case $\alpha <1$ it seems that we can't conclude if we don't know how $\sum u_n^\alpha$ behaves. What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: @user I think it's inconclusive for $\alpha<1$

Comment: Yes I agree with that! There are not sufficient information. What we can say is that the series behaves as $\sum u_n^\alpha$.

Comment: Yes of course, I was giving that as a known fact! :)